# Solving system of equations in polar and Cartesian coordinates, involving a Fourier series

Tags: linear-algebra, fourier-series, matrix-calculus

I have an equation of body surface is polar coordinates defined as Fourier series:
$$
r=r_{0} + \sum [a_{i}\cos(i\phi) + b_{i}\sin(i\phi)]
$$
Also I have a line equation in Cartesian coordinates: $y=kx+b$

I need to find their point of intersection. How can I do this? I guess, I should use a transformation matrix. But I don't understand, how it should be.
I think, this matrix will help me with transformation a Fourier series equation to Cartesian coordinates, or vice versa line equation to polar coordinates and later solve the system of equations.

Comment: I think you need to use Euler's formula: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula

Comment: @noumenal I'm not sure, because I don't use complex numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no hope for an analytic solution. I would transform the line equation into polar coordinates:
$$
r = \frac{b}{\sin\phi-k\cos\phi}
$$
and then use a numerical method to find an intersection point. This amounts to finding a root of 
$$
\left(r_{0} + \sum [a_{i}\cos(i\phi) + b_{i}\sin(i\phi)] \right)({\sin\phi-k\cos\phi}) - b = 0
$$
The expression on the left is a trigonometric sum, so it's not hard to find its derivative and use [the Newton–Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method).